# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, foreign-keys

I get this error from SQL Server:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASENAME", table "TABLE", column 'UserID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

This came from Visual Studio 2008:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

This is what I got

```
CREATE TABLE DATABASENAME.TABLE 
(
    UserID INT IDENTITY,
    ...
    ...

    CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (UserID),
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE DATABASENAME.OTHERTABLE 
(
    ...
    ...
    ManagerUserID INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT FK FOREIGN KEY (ManagerUserID) REFERENCES TABLE (UserID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STOREDPROCEDURENAME
(@ManagerUserID int,   
 ...
 ...
)
AS 
    INSERT INTO OTHERTABLE(..., ManagerUserID, ...)
    VALUES (..., @ManagerUserID, ...)
```

This came form c#

```
_projectID = Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar( 
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[TimeWeb.Web.Global.CfgKeyConnString],
 "STOREDPROCEDURENAME", ..., ..., _managerID, ...));
```

When I'm adding data on the webpage in this case I mean about the user, from methods I get the right `UserID`. But then happens this.

So in TABLE I got the `UserID` added of course, but in the moment when I'm making the stored procedure working in, the first message appears.

Can't realize what is wrong with my code. Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you calling this stored procedure from C#? if yes then show us code if no remove C# tag from question. :)

Comment: I can't spot any problem in the code that you have shown, so it's more likely that the problem is in the code that calls the procedure, e.g. that the value that you send in for `@ManagerUserID` is not what you think.

Comment: Code added, this is what is in the page. Sorry this is my first question.

Comment: From DB Perspective, you are trying to insert value into the column DATABASENAME.OTHERTABLE.ManagerUserID which is not in DATABASENAME.TABLE.UserID......unless you have Foreign Key in place you will get this error.

Comment: @knkarthick24 i thought that too, but in DATABASENAME.TABLE.UserID  i got 6 users all of them with their respective ID Example : 2, 26, 167,172. ... They have names . When i run the SP with ID 172, that's the problem with the FK. I don't know what is going on in there.

Answer (score 0):

For Your Store procedure.

try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STOREDPROCEDURENAME
(@ManagerUserID int,   
 ...
 ...
)
AS 
Begin
 if exists(select * from DATABASENAME.TABLE where UserID=@ManagerUserID) --check if pk exists to the ref rable
   begin
   INSERT INTO OTHERTABLE(..., ManagerUserID, ...)
     VALUES (..., @ManagerUserID, ...)
   end
End
```